# Roll to see all sides!

Tags: sequence, combinatorics, fastest-code

Let's say you have a 20-sided die. You start rolling that die and have to roll it a few dozen times before  you finally roll all 20 values. You wonder, how many rolls do I need before I get a 50% chance of seeing all 20 values? And how many rolls of an `n`-sided die do I need to roll before I roll all `n` sides?

After some research, you find out that a formula exists for calculating the **chance** of rolling all `n` values after `r` rolls.

```
P(r, n) = n! * S(r, n) / n**r
```

where `S(a, b)` denotes [Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind), the number of ways to partition a set of n objects (each roll) into k non-empty subsets (each side).

You also find the [OEIS sequence](http://oeis.org/A073593), which we'll call `R(n)`, that corresponds to the smallest `r` where `P(r, n)` is at least 50%. The challenge is to calculate the `n`th term of this sequence as fast as possible.

**The challenge**

- Given an `n`, find the **smallest** `r` where `P(r, n)` is greater than or equal to `0.5` or 50%.
- Your code should theoretically handle any non-negative integer `n` as input, but we will only be testing your code in the range of `1 <= n <= 1000000`.
- For scoring, we will be take the total time required to run `R(n)` on inputs `1` through `10000`.
- We will check if your solutions are correct by running our version of `R(n)` on your output to see if `P(your_output, n) >= 0.5` and `P(your_output - 1, n) < 0.5`, i.e. that your output is actually the smallest `r` for a given `n`.
- You may use any definition for `S(a, b)` in your solution. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) has several definitions that may be helpful here.
- You may use built-ins in your solutions, including those that calculate `S(a, b)`, or even those that calculate `P(r, n)` directly.
- You can hardcode up to 1000 values of `R(n)` and a million Stirling numbers, though neither of these are hard limits, and can be changed if you can make a convincing argument for raising or lowering them.
- You don't need to check every possible `r` between `n` and the `r` we're looking for, but you do need to find the smallest `r` and not just any `r` where `P(r, n) >= 0.5`.
- Your program must use a language that is freely runnable on Windows 10.

The specifications of the computer that will test your solutions are `i7 4790k, 8 GB RAM`. Thanks to [@DJMcMayhem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31716/djmcmayhem) for providing his computer for the testing. Feel free to add your own *unofficial* timing for reference, but the official timing will be provided later once DJ can test it.

**Test cases**

```
n       R(n)
1       1
2       2
3       5
4       7
5       10
6       13
20      67       # our 20-sided die
52      225      # how many cards from a huge uniformly random pile until we get a full deck
100     497
366     2294     # number of people for to get 366 distinct birthdays
1000    7274
2000    15934
5000    44418
10000   95768
100000  1187943
1000000 14182022
```

Let me know if you have any questions or suggestions. Good luck and good optimizing!

Comment: @JonathanAllan Knew I should have chosen a different wording. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 7):

## Python + NumPy, 3.95 Seconds

```python
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np

def rolls(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    r = n * (np.log(n) - np.log(np.log(2)))
    x = np.log1p(np.arange(n) / -n)
    cx = x.cumsum()
    y = cx[:-1] + cx[-2::-1] - cx[-1]
    while True:
        r0 = np.round(r)
        z = np.exp(y + r0 * x[1:])
        z[::2] *= -1
        r = r0 - (z.sum() + 0.5) / z.dot(x[1:])
        if abs(r - r0) < 0.75:
            return np.ceil(r).astype(int)

for n in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 20, 52, 100, 366, 1000, 2000, 5000, 10000, 100000, 1000000]:
    print('R({}) = {}'.format(n, rolls(n)))

import timeit
print('Benchmark: {:.2f}s'.format(timeit.timeit(lambda: sum(map(rolls, range(1, 10001))), number=1)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVJNb6MwEL3zK@ZWkwKLySaVULnsT1jtLUKRA6axFn/IQAuJ8tvTsd2kUX3wzDy/NzMe2yzjUav19dpZLWG/76Zxsny/ByGNtiO04l0MQqvoK1aTNAuwAZSJopZ3YHXfD0TFZQS4RAcKqgpoCN2yHDMqoB6wUCFhBUSZrNdvqIMUbn4wRRzHnjs7rseocYfMMvXGneQXpCpwGkeas2aSwyRJwBaEmnlXprSGZ@elRemD1Ae09qyPo@g5/LMTf2g1DyWtnlRLbHw/OAWcz4YsmBN5K5h3tKwfKLuyLGpYVZDS74SoQ3IK5JT5BlGcZxt3g1PW6pH8SILjY4eBWFTYPIZXJL9svvt7GCd203DRY5MZG8bFcCLUGF87bXG@QsGOJlAksE7gdwKbBLYY5ughRnN01tut93KHu33jd4fczN3mdWjBWKxBnv6S8yXGi50vTxnWk2wkKrn/A3y8218ZheRijL5kf7hqjpLZ/yWcy6zoLsNdHohZMKRn8tCyEtzAJDPEZ8YC/vVpaIpincR9xgO3lQuunw)

#### How it works

This uses the closed-form series for *P*(*r*, *n*), and its derivative with respect to *r*, rearranged for numerical stability and vectorization, to do a Newton’s method search for *r* such that *P*(*r*, *n*) = 0.5, rounding *r* to an integer before each step, until the step moves *r* by less than 3/4.  With a good initial guess, this usually takes just one or two iterations.

*x*<sub>*i*</sub> = log(1 − *i*/*n*) = log((*n* − *i*)/*n*)
*cx*<sub>*i*</sub> = log(*n*!/((*n* − *i* − 1)! ⋅ *n*<sup>*i* + 1</sup>)
*y*<sub>*i*</sub> = *cx*<sub>*i*</sub> + *cx*<sub>*n* − *i* − 2</sub> − *cx*<sub>*n* − 1</sub> = log binom(*n*, *i* + 1)
*z*<sub>*i*</sub> = (-1)<sup>*i* + 1</sup> ⋅ binom(*n*, *i* + 1) ⋅ ((*n* − *i* − 1)/*n*)<sup>*r*</sup>
1 + ∑*z*<sub>*i*</sub> = n! ⋅ *S*(*r*, *n*)/*n*<sup>*r*</sup> = *P*(*r*, *n*)
*z*<sub>*i*</sub> ⋅ *x*<sub>*i* + 1</sub> = (-1)<sup>*i* + 1</sup> ⋅ binom(*n*, *i* + 1) ⋅ ((*n* − *i* − 1)/*n*)<sup>*r*</sup> log((*n* − *i* − 1)/*n*)
∑*z*<sub>*i*</sub> ⋅ *x*<sub>*i* + 1</sub> = d/d*r* *P*(*r*, *n*)

Comment: Excellent work on the whole answer! First, I should have realized that `0.366512` was the `log` of something ages ago. Will use `-log(log(2)` in my next iteration. Second, the idea to use Newton's method is also very clever and I'm glad to see that this works so well. Third, I'm almost definitely going to steal `exp(log(binom(n, i+1)) + r * log((n-i-1)/n))` :P Kudos on a great answer! :D

Comment: I've added the official timing! Nice answer BTW :)

Comment: I'm really confused. I changed the `numpy` import to `from numpy import *` and for some reason the time dropped to basically 0... [Try it online](http://bit.ly/2v9D34V)?

Comment: @notjagan cache hit maybe?

Comment: @notjagan That’s because `numpy.sum` doesn’t know how to iterate over a `map` object and instead returns the `map` object back without evaluating anything.

Comment: I'd like to apologize for several things: 1) my plagiarism of your answer when I tried to find improvements; 2) not owning up to it properly and just trying to fix my answer; 3) that this apology has taken so long. I was so mortified that at first I just abandoned this challenge. In a small attempt at reparation, I suppose it fair to tell you that my main improvement on this answer was changing from Newton's method to incrementing `r`, as your initial approximation is already quite good. Hope to see you in PPCG once more, and sorry for everything.